# Proof of Uniqueness of $q$ and $r$ in Quotient and Remainder Theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, divisibility

My Professor presented the following theorem:

> **Theorem** If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then there exist unique $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>
> $$a = bq + r$$ and $$0 \le r < b$$

And then the following proof of uniqueness:

> Suppose $q$ and $r$ are not unique, and so
>
> $$a = qb + r = q'b + r',$$ with $$0 \le r \le r' < b$$
>
> i.e. assume, WLOG, that $r' \ge r$.
>
> If $r' > r$, then $0 < r' - r < b$, and the expressions for $a$ imply
>
> $$0 \le (q - q')b = r' - r < b,$$
>
> which is impossible.
>
> Thus $r' = r$ and $qb + r = q' b + r$ implies $q = q'$, so the two expressions for $a$ are the same.

But this proof begins by assuming that $q$ and $r$ are not unique; specifically, that $r' \ge r$. If we get a contradiction during this, then doesn't that simply prove that $r' \not\ge r$? In that case, we still haven't ruled out whether $r' < r$. So, in the end, it seems like the proof doesn't necessarily prove that $r' = r$, as it claims?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Since $r$ and $r'$ are real numbers they are ordered, and one of these three cases must be true: $r'<r$, or $r'=r$ or $r'>r$.  If $r'>r$ we can relabel $r$ to be $r'$ and $r'$ to be $r$ to obtain $r'<r$ again.  That's what the "WLOG" means -- that we only need to consider the two cases.  Can you now see how the proof by contradiction works?

Comment: @postmortes Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

WLOG we could choose such that $r > r'$ as otherwise we could simply just swap the variables.

By property of $\mathbb{Z}$, $(q - q') b \: < \: b$ is only possible if $q - q' = 0$ thus $q = q'$. As $(q - q')b = 0b = 0 = r - r'$, thus again $r = r'$.